# JetBrains IntelliJ Remote Development does not open my project

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-gateway

JetBrains IntelliJ 2023.2.4

I had been using the "Remote development" feature from JetBrains successfully for 3+ months with this version when suddenly an upgrade to the 2023.3 has stopped working. I happened to delete my backends so I am unable to rollback.

When I use "Gateway" and start a project it creates a backend and then waits for connecting to the backend then throws an error see screenshot below.

The logs do not indicate much except that I get loads of errors of the form

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/X11R6/bin/xauth": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:470)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.startProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:443)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:348)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
```

and also some errors of the form

```
2024-01-04 09:21:08,491 WARN    exit code: 1    /bin/zsh -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/keekanat/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ host-status\ --ide-path=/home/keekanat/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/7d0ec4c5e721d_ideaIU-2023.3.2\ --project-path=/local/home/keekanat/workplace/PVFinSysVariableEndToEndTests
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    {"type":"error","errorCode":"CommandError","data":"Command /home/keekanat/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/7d0ec4c5e721d_ideaIU-2023.3.2/bin/remote-dev-server.sh failed.\nStdout: IDE config directory: /home/keekanat/.config/JetBrains/RemoteDev-IU/_local_home_keekanat_workplace_PVFinSysVariableEndToEndTests\nIDE system directory: /home/keekanat/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-IU/_local_home_keekanat_workplace_PVFinSysVariableEndToEndTests\nEnable JDK auto-detection and project SDK setup by default. Set REMOTE_DEV_JDK_DETECTION=false to disable.\nIs running inside Docker container: 0\nCompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true\nIDE has not been initialized yet\n\nStderr: \n\nCaused by: exit status 14"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With some hassle I figured out that the directories that matter are under `.cache` and `.config` so when I did

```
mv /home/USER/.cache/JetBrains /home/USER/.cache/JetBrains-2023-01-04
mv /home/USER/.config/JetBrains /home/USER/.config/JetBrains-2023-01-04
```

it all seemed to work. It might be useful from the UI to present an option like "Everything is Kaput... do you want to really start everything fresh with new config and cache"?

Comment: *"It might be useful from the UI to present an option like "Everything is Kaput... do you want to really start everything fresh with new config and cache"?"* Where did you execute those commands (renaming folders)? On a local machine or remote one? If local -- try `File | Repair IDE` next time -- it might be able to resolve the issue (it has a few steps, will also check settings and caches etc)

Comment: I had to ssh into the remote and do this. Not sure if I can do File -> repair IDE if the IDE does not open?

Answer (score 0):

> so when I did

Actually, you're not supposed to do these things manually. According to this part of the log, the remote IDE didn't start, so it didn't provide an expected reply to the local component (Gateway). It's better to show the remote side logs to the support (if you still have them).

Comment: That is all okay but unfortunately I "cannot" wait until some support team fixes a problem. I need to progress immediately.